# Check if a binary tree is traversed from left to right in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have the following tree and this is how I access the Int values of its nodes and leaves. What I want to do is to write a function "areValuesIncreasing" to check if the values of the nodes/leaves are increasing as the tree is traversed from left to right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
       4                    4
     /   \                /   \
    2     3              3     2
   / \   / \            / \   / \
  1   3 4   5  - True  1   3 5   4 - False



   data Tree = Node Tree Int Tree | Leaf Int deriving Show

   treeToInt (Node _ n _) = n
   treeToInt (Leaf n ) = n

   areValuesIncreasing:: Tree -> Bool
```

Comment: Sounds like you just want to check if the tree is a BST.

Comment: @RoadRunner, no, he doesn't, as the example tree isn't a BST and yet passes.

Answer (score -1):

I heavily recommend changing `Tree` to

```
data Tree a = Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
            | Leaf a 
            deriving (...)
```

and will use this in my answer, but transforming it to your `Tree` is as easy as setting `a ~ Int` everywhere and replacing `Tree Int` with `Tree`.

Create a list of elements for each layer, and then check that all of those are sorted. Assuming you have a function

```
foldTree :: (a -> b) ->           -- Leaf case
            (b -> a -> b -> b) -> -- Node case
            Tree a -> b
```

The leaves produce a list containing a singleton list followed by `repeat []`, as a leaf is a single element on a level followed by infinitely many empty levels

```
leafCase x = [x] : repeat []
```

And the internal nodes concatenate the subtrees' lists' sublists pairwise, while also placing their element in a singleton list on top:

```
nodeCase l x r = [x] : zipWith (++) l r
```

Fold this over a `Tree` to get a list of levels, and cut it off after the last nonempty one:

```
levels = takeWhile (not . null) . foldTree leafCase nodeCase
```

Check that each level is sorted:

```
sorted = all (uncurry (<=)) . (zip <*> tail)
```

Mix it all up into one function

```
sortedTree = all sorted . takeWhile (not . null) . levels
  where sorted = all (uncurry (<=)) . (zip <*> tail)
        levels = foldTree (\l -> [l] : repeat []) (\l x r -> [x] : zipWith (++) l r)
```

---

Same thing with `recursion-schemes`:

```
makeBaseFunctor ''Tree
-- data TreeF a b = NodeF b a b | LeafF a
-- ...
levelsSorted :: (Recursive t, Foldable (Base t), Ord a) => (Base t [[a]] -> a) -> t -> Bool
levelsSorted get = all sorted . takeWhile (not . null) . levels
    where sorted = all (uncurry (<=)) . (zip <*> tail)
          levels = cata $ \x -> [get x] : foldr (zipWith (++)) (repeat []) x

levelsSortedTree :: Ord a => Tree a -> Bool
levelsSortedTree = levelsSorted $ \case { LeafF _ x _ -> x; NodeF x -> x }
```

Comment: I downvoted this answer because your `Tree` is a partial record, which is bad advice.